# Retrieve all data from query

Tags: django

I keep struggling with Django Model, Managers' relations.

I have a Profile model, Product Model, and Holding model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, through='Holding')


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)



class Product(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    product_slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)
    product_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)
    product_price = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_name)


class Holding(models.Model):

    product_name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_holding = models.FloatField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_name)
```

I'm trying to retrieve the data from a user `(Profile)` for a Product within `Holding` Basically I want to show the amount of a product a user is currently holding.

I'm doing this in my view

```
def show_product_details(request, product_name):
    product = product.objects.get(Product_name=product_name)
    ...

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    product_holding = profile.holding_set.get(product_name__product_name = product_name)

     return render(request, 'productdetails.html', {'product_holding':product_holding ...}
```

But this isn't returning all the data, but instead just the `product_name`.

What am i doing wrong.? :(

Comment: Why do you think it's only returning the product name? Can you share the code where you can't access the other data?

Comment: cause when i do `{{product_holding}}` it just prints the product name

Comment: Thia ia because you define `return str(self.product_name)` on the `Holding` model. But you can also access other data like `{{ product_holding.product_holding }}`

Comment: Ha, i tried that and nothing happened. Thanks.

Comment: When you say `isn't returning all the data` you mean all the data in the object? or that you expect multiple records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line

```
product_holding = profile.holding_set.get(product_name__product_name = product_name)
```

You are accessing Product model (product_name field in Holding model) and then from this model you are accessing field "product_name" which correspond to

```
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
```

in Product model. So you are getting just the name of it.

If you want to get the whole model data then use just:

```
product_holding = profile.holding_set.get(product_name = product_name)
```

And the you can access each field by using

```
{{product_name.product_name}}
{{product_name.product_price}}
```